# Simplify template arguments

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

I need to create a template class depending on a simple struct like this. It has a method `AddNew` to insert new element for its tuple member.

```
struct Type
{
  int i;
  char c;
};

template<typename ...T>
class A
{
   std::tuple<T...> ts;
   public:
     A(T&&...t):ts(std::move(t)...){}
     void AddNew(T t)
     {
        ts=std::tuple_cat(ts,t);
     }
};

int main()
{
   A<Type,Type,Type,Type> a({1,'a'},{2,'t'},{3,'c'},{4,'g'});
   Type t{5,'x'};
   a.AddNew(t);
}
```

Problem I don't want to write down `Type`... 4 times like in `main`. I like something like `A<Type,4>` when I initialize `A` with 4 `Type`s or `A<Type, 100>` for 100 `Type`s.

Comment: I don't think that's possible, since the template types can be heterogeneous.

Comment: `tuple_cat` doesn't work like this

Comment: [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may partially specialize A for some helper 'tag' type:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
struct repeat{};

template<typename... T>
struct repeat_unpack{ using type = A<T...>; };

template<typename T, int N, typename... V >
struct repeat_unpack<repeat<T,N>,V...>: std::conditional_t<(N>1),
    repeat_unpack<repeat<T,N-1>,T,V...>,
    repeat_unpack<T,V...>
 >{};

template<typename T, int N>
class A<repeat<T,N>>: repeat_unpack<repeat<T,N>>::type {};

// to be used as
A<repeat<Type,3>>
```

the above uses inheritance to avoid code duplication, so you'll probably need to lift some members (eg. constructors) to the partial specialization as well.
Otherwise, just use an alias

```
template<class T, std::size_t N>
using A_nth = typename repeat_unpack<repeat<T,N>>::type;

A_nth<Type,3>
```

Just one more thing, given that you're using tuple internally, it should be easy to simply specialize for std::array and use it instead, being tuple compatible ...

PS. obviously, your `AddNew()` code makes no sense as is, I'd assume it's just a code snippet typo ...

Comment: It doesn't look typo-y. There seems to be some serious misconception

Comment: @PasserBy yep, but it looks so wrong that it must be right somehow :) anyway, the question still makes sense on itself ... waiting for OP clarifications

Comment: :=]] Thank you a lot, you are right. I can't hide anything from you.

Answer (score 3):

You probably just want vector:

```
struct Type
{
  int i;
  char c;
};

template<typename T>
class A
{
   std::vector<T> data;
   public:
     template <typename ... Ts>
     A(Ts&&...ts) : data(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...){}

     void AddNew(const T& t)
     {
        data.push_back(t);
     }
};

int main()
{
   A<Type> a(Type{1,'a'}, Type{2,'t'}, Type{3,'c'}, Type{4,'g'});
   Type t{5,'x'};
   a.AddNew(t);
}
```